# How do I use the results of WP in another plug-in?

Tags: ocaml, frama-c

I am working on writing a Frama-C plug-in and I would like to know if it is possible to get the weakest precondition of something using WP from within my plug-in, and if so, how exactly? In the past I've used Db.Value, for example, to use the results of the EVA plug-in in my own plug-in. Is there something similar to Db.Value for WP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `WP` plugin exposes its API in the `WP.mli` file, that is generated by collecting the interfaces of the higher-level modules composing `Wp`. you can find it in `src/plugins/wp/Wp.mli`.

However, you should be aware that this API should not be considered stable, and non-backward compatible changes may be introduced in newer Frama-C versions.